# change input value which is inside td upon chekcing checkbox on same tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
<table class="table" id="ptable" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CheckBoxes</th>
            <th>SL</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_9">
            </td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Product-9
                <input type="number" class="pmqty" id="qty_9" name="qty[]" value="18">
            </td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_10">
            </td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Product-10
                <input type="number" class="pmqty" id="qty_10" name="qty[]" value="20">
            </td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_15">
            </td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Product-23
                <input type="number" class="pmqty" id="qty_15" name="qty[]" value="199">
            </td>
            <td>150</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_18">
            </td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Product-12
                <input type="number" class="pmqty" id="qty_18" name="qty[]" value="67">
            </td>
            <td>200</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am looking for something which will do this:
if you check a checkbox of a row, the value of input field inside the td will be zero, if uncheck again, the value will be restored.

this table if dynamically created so, I can use Id on every checkbox or every input field too.

Comment: show what you have tried to achieve above

Answer (score 1):

The shortest possible native JS solution:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach((el)=>{

el.onclick = function() {
input = el.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('input[type="number"]');
input.value != 0?input.setAttribute('data-val',input.value):0;
input.value = input.value == input.getAttribute('data-val')?0:input.getAttribute('data-val');

}});
```

```html
<table class="table" id="ptable" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CheckBoxes</th>
            <th>SL</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_9" >
            </td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Product-9
                <input type="number" class="pmqty" id="qty_9" name="qty[]" value="18">
            </td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_10">
            </td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Product-10
                <input type="number" class="pmqty" id="qty_10" name="qty[]" value="20">
            </td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_15">
            </td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Product-23
                <input type="number" class="pmqty" id="qty_15" name="qty[]" value="199">
            </td>
            <td>150</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_18">
            </td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Product-12
                <input type="number" class="pmqty" id="qty_18" name="qty[]" value="67">
            </td>
            <td>200</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: My pleasure, @ErfanAlam!

Answer (score 0):

Simple , check value of  checkbox if clicked ,

- if checked  then use dom traversing closest() + find()  to gt input , store value in data attribute (in order to reset it once uncheked) , then set value to 0
- if unchecked restore value from data attrbiute already set .

  ```
  $(".form-check-input").on('click', function() {
       let $input = $(this).closest('tr').find('.pmqty');

       if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

         $input.data("prev-value", $input.val());
         $input.val(0);


      } else {
         $input.val($input.data("prev-value"));

      }

  })
  ```

See below working snippet :

```js
$(function() {

  $(".form-check-input").on('click', function() {
    let $input = $(this).closest('tr').find('.pmqty');

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $input.data("prev-value", $input.val());
      $input.val(0);
      //if($input.length)

    } else {
      $input.val($input.data("prev-value"));

    }

  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="ptable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>CheckBoxes</th>
      <th>SL</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_9">
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Product-9
        <input type="number" class="pmqty" id="qty_9" name="qty[]" value="18">
      </td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_10">
      </td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Product-10
        <input type="number" class="pmqty" id="qty_10" name="qty[]" value="20">
      </td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_15">
      </td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Product-23
        <input type="number" class="pmqty" id="qty_15" name="qty[]" value="199">
      </td>
      <td>150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_18">
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Product-12
        <input type="number" class="pmqty" id="qty_18" name="qty[]" value="67">
      </td>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you have 20 products in order from 1 to 20 for this loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    var checkboxID = "#check_" + String(i);
    var numberID = "#qty_" + String(i);
    var checkbox = document.querySelector(checkboxID);
    var number = document.querySelector(numberID);
    number.setAttribute("hidden-number", number.value);
    checkbox.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (number.value == 0) {
            number.value = number.getAttribute("hidden-number");
        }
        else {
            number.value = 0;
        }
        
    });
}
```

This program loops through all your numbers and checkboxes and stores the original value, then it sets up a toggle that will toggle the value based on the checkbox being clicked or not. I know it's not a conventional approach but that's my take on it.

Answer (score 0):

See description below in JS code... Basically create an event listener for each checkbox element. Then use the key from the input loop to identify the `pmqty` classes.

Save your initial values in an array for when the box is not clicked and set that in your conditional else...

```js
let chkBox = document.querySelectorAll('.form-check-input');
let pmqty = document.querySelectorAll('.pmqty');
let pmqtyArr = [];

// get the values of the product input fields and place them in an array
pmqty.forEach((pmq)=>{
  pmqtyArr.push(pmq.value);
})

// iterate over the checkboxes and establish a key and a value
chkBox.forEach((box, i) => {
  // use the box value to add an eventlistener to each element
  box.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
    // conditional that checks the event target is checked
    if(e.target.checked){ 
      // if it is checked (true), set the other input classes value to '0'
      pmqty[i].value = "0";
    }else{ 
      // else set the input classes value to the arrays value
      pmqty[i].value = pmqtyArr[i];
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<table class="table" id="ptable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>CheckBoxes</th>
      <th>SL</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_9">
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Product-9
        <input type="number" class="pmqty" id="qty_9" name="qty[]" value="18">
      </td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_10">
      </td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Product-10
        <input type="number" class="pmqty" id="qty_10" name="qty[]" value="20">
      </td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_15">
      </td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Product-23
        <input type="number" class="pmqty" id="qty_15" name="qty[]" value="199">
      </td>
      <td>150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check_18">
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Product-12
        <input type="number" class="pmqty" id="qty_18" name="qty[]" value="67">
      </td>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```